# Should I checkin pkg/mod/cache to git?

Tags: go, go-modules, go-packages

I'm using go mod for my project. If my understanding is right, go.mod and go.sum can be checked in. However, I'm curious to know if I should check in `pkg/mod/cache as well`.

[image]

Comment: No. That shouldn't even be a subdirectory of your project folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I checkin pkg/mod/cache to git?

No.

If you want to vendor your dependencies use `go mod vendor`.